# PHP date/time format, need some assistance

Tags: php, date, time, format

can you please help me with formatting the following date using PHP

variable $start contains the following date

this date

```
Wed Feb 01 2012 05:00:00 GMT-080
```

should become

```
2012-02-01T13:00:00
```

I know how to use basic PHP date/time formats, but this one is a bit though-er,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$d = new \DateTime('Wed Feb 01 2012 05:00:00 GMT-080');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Comment: No problem. Both answers are correct -- the only difference is whether you want to do it procedurally or using OOP.

Comment: something is going wrong, the following: $newdate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($start)); saved 1970-01-01T00:00:00 to the database, if I just use $start, Wed Feb 01 2012 03:20:00 GMT-080 is saved to the database. What is going wrong?

Comment: @MaartenHartman if `1970-01-01T00:00:00` is being saved into your database when you use `strtotime($start)` it means `strtotime` couldn't parse the `$start` string provided. Make sure the string you're providing is one that `strtotime` can understand. `1970-01-01T00:00:00` is the sames result you'll get if you do `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', 0);`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime('Wed Feb 01 2012 05:00:00 GMT-0800'));
```